Failure to insert citations into R visual markdown - no bibliography, in text citation starts with @
I am unable to find a solution, I have tried googling, but haven't had any luck finding a solution. Briefly, it used to work, but ever since I installed better bibtex, it does not work at all. Now, no citations work, regardless of if it is through zotero or not!
See the screenshots for a brief account of the issue.
enter image description here
I tried various settings, uninstalling and reinstalling software, disabling better bibtex.
